# Python HTMLTestRunner not generating report

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am having an problem in generating html report with HTMLTestRunner. I have created a test suite in a file called TestsSuite.py. Here's the code excerpt:

```
import unittest
from LoginTest import LoginTest
from EditProfileTest import ProfileEditionTest
from EditAddressTest import EditAddressTest
from CreatePostTest import CreatePostTest
from HTMLTestRunner import HTMLTestRunner

def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(LoginTest())
    suite.addTest(ProfileEditionTest())
    suite().addTest(EditAddressTest)
    suite().addTest(CreatePostTest)
    return suite
if ____name____ == "____main___":
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
    outfile = open('C:/Report.html', 'w')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile,verbosity=2,title='LinkedIn Report',description='This is a demo report')
    runner.run(suite())
```

When I run this piece of code, it runs to completion with all test cases displayed as pass in PyUnit but when I open Report.html, the file is displayed blank.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Hi I have Modified the Code inside HTMLTestRunner.py file to work with Python 3.x and followed the normal process to import the module as usual
Hope it might help

```
"""
A TestRunner for use with the Python unit testing framework. It
generates a HTML report to show the result at a glance.

The simplest way to use this is to invoke its main method. E.g.

    import unittest
    import HTMLTestRunner

    ... define your tests ...

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        HTMLTestRunner.main()


For more customization options, instantiates a HTMLTestRunner object.
HTMLTestRunner is a counterpart to unittest's TextTestRunner. E.g.

    # output to a file
    fp = file('my_report.html', 'wb')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
                stream=fp,
                title='My unit test',
                description='This demonstrates the report output by HTMLTestRunner.'
                )

    # Use an external stylesheet.
    # See the Template_mixin class for more customizable options
    runner.STYLESHEET_TMPL = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="my_stylesheet.css" type="text/css">'

    # run the test
    runner.run(my_test_suite)


------------------------------------------------------------------------
Copyright (c) 2004-2007, Wai Yip Tung
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
met:

* Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
* Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
  notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
  documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
* Neither the name Wai Yip Tung nor the names of its contributors may be
  used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without
  specific prior written permission.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER
OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
"""

# URL: http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html

__author__ = "Wai Yip Tung"
__version__ = "0.8.2"


"""
Change History

Version 0.8.2
* Show output inline instead of popup window (Viorel Lupu).

Version in 0.8.1
* Validated XHTML (Wolfgang Borgert).
* Added description of test classes and test cases.

Version in 0.8.0
* Define Template_mixin class for customization.
* Workaround a IE 6 bug that it does not treat <script> block as CDATA.

Version in 0.7.1
* Back port to Python 2.3 (Frank Horowitz).
* Fix missing scroll bars in detail log (Podi).
"""

# TODO: color stderr
# TODO: simplify javascript using ,ore than 1 class in the class attribute?

import datetime
import sys
import time
import unittest
from xml.sax import saxutils
from io import StringIO


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The redirectors below are used to capture output during testing. Output
# sent to sys.stdout and sys.stderr are automatically captured. However
# in some cases sys.stdout is already cached before HTMLTestRunner is
# invoked (e.g. calling logging.basicConfig). In order to capture those
# output, use the redirectors for the cached stream.
#
# e.g.
#   >>> logging.basicConfig(stream=HTMLTestRunner.stdout_redirector)
#   >>>

class OutputRedirector(object):
    """ Wrapper to redirect stdout or stderr """
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.fp = fp

    def write(self, s):
        self.fp.write(s)

    def writelines(self, lines):
        self.fp.writelines(lines)

    def flush(self):
        self.fp.flush()

stdout_redirector = OutputRedirector(sys.stdout)
stderr_redirector = OutputRedirector(sys.stderr)



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Template

class Template_mixin(object):
    """
    Define a HTML template for report customerization and generation.

    Overall structure of an HTML report

    HTML
    +------------------------+
    |<html>                  |
    |  <head>                |
    |                        |
    |   STYLESHEET           |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |   |                |   |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |                        |
    |  </head>               |
    |                        |
    |  <body>                |
    |                        |
    |   HEADING              |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |   |                |   |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |                        |
    |   REPORT               |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |   |                |   |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |                        |
    |   ENDING               |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |   |                |   |
    |   +----------------+   |
    |                        |
    |  </body>               |
    |</html>                 |
    +------------------------+
    """

    STATUS = {
    0: 'pass',
    1: 'fail',
    2: 'error',
    }

    DEFAULT_TITLE = 'Unit Test Report'
    DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION = ''

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # HTML Template

    HTML_TMPL = r"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>%(title)s</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="%(generator)s"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    %(stylesheet)s
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
output_list = Array();

/* level - 0:Summary; 1:Failed; 2:All */
function showCase(level) {
    trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        tr = trs[i];
        id = tr.id;
        if (id.substr(0,2) == 'ft') {
            if (level < 1) {
                tr.className = 'hiddenRow';
            }
            else {
                tr.className = '';
            }
        }
        if (id.substr(0,2) == 'pt') {
            if (level > 1) {
                tr.className = '';
            }
            else {
                tr.className = 'hiddenRow';
            }
        }
    }
}


function showClassDetail(cid, count) {
    var id_list = Array(count);
    var toHide = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        tid0 = 't' + cid.substr(1) + '.' + (i+1);
        tid = 'f' + tid0;
        tr = document.getElementById(tid);
        if (!tr) {
            tid = 'p' + tid0;
            tr = document.getElementById(tid);
        }
        id_list[i] = tid;
        if (tr.className) {
            toHide = 0;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        tid = id_list[i];
        if (toHide) {
            document.getElementById('div_'+tid).style.display = 'none'
            document.getElementById(tid).className = 'hiddenRow';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(tid).className = '';
        }
    }
}


function showTestDetail(div_id){
    var details_div = document.getElementById(div_id)
    var displayState = details_div.style.display
    // alert(displayState)
    if (displayState != 'block' ) {
        displayState = 'block'
        details_div.style.display = 'block'
    }
    else {
        details_div.style.display = 'none'
    }
}


function html_escape(s) {
    s = s.replace(/&/g,'&amp;');
    s = s.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
    s = s.replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
    return s;
}

/* obsoleted by detail in <div>
function showOutput(id, name) {
    var w = window.open("", //url
                    name,
                    "resizable,scrollbars,status,width=800,height=450");
    d = w.document;
    d.write("<pre>");
    d.write(html_escape(output_list[id]));
    d.write("\n");
    d.write("<a href='javascript:window.close()'>close</a>\n");
    d.write("</pre>\n");
    d.close();
}
*/
--></script>

%(heading)s
%(report)s
%(ending)s

</body>
</html>
"""
    # variables: (title, generator, stylesheet, heading, report, ending)


    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Stylesheet
    #
    # alternatively use a <link> for external style sheet, e.g.
    #   <link rel="stylesheet" href="$url" type="text/css">

    STYLESHEET_TMPL = """
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body        { font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 80%; }
table       { font-size: 100%; }
pre         { }

/* -- heading ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
h1 {
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: gray;
}
.heading {
    margin-top: 0ex;
    margin-bottom: 1ex;
}

.heading .attribute {
    margin-top: 1ex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.heading .description {
    margin-top: 4ex;
    margin-bottom: 6ex;
}

/* -- css div popup ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
a.popup_link {
}

a.popup_link:hover {
    color: red;
}

.popup_window {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    /*border: solid #627173 1px; */
    /*padding: 10px; */
    background-color: #E6E6D6;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 8pt;
    /*width: 500px;*/
}

}
/* -- report ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
#show_detail_line {
    margin-top: 3ex;
    margin-bottom: 1ex;
}
#result_table {
    width: 80%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
#header_row {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color: #777;
}
#result_table td {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    padding: 2px;
}
#total_row  { font-weight: bold; }
.passClass  { background-color: #6c6; }
.failClass  { background-color: #c60; }
.errorClass { background-color: #c00; }
.passCase   { color: #6c6; }
.failCase   { color: #c60; font-weight: bold; }
.errorCase  { color: #c00; font-weight: bold; }
.hiddenRow  { display: none; }
.testcase   { margin-left: 2em; }


/* -- ending ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#ending {
}

</style>
"""



    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Heading
    #

    HEADING_TMPL = """<div class='heading'>
<h1>%(title)s</h1>
%(parameters)s
<p class='description'>%(description)s</p>
</div>

""" # variables: (title, parameters, description)

    HEADING_ATTRIBUTE_TMPL = """<p class='attribute'><strong>%(name)s:</strong> %(value)s</p>
""" # variables: (name, value)



    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Report
    #

    REPORT_TMPL = """
<p id='show_detail_line'>Show
<a href='javascript:showCase(0)'>Summary</a>
<a href='javascript:showCase(1)'>Failed</a>
<a href='javascript:showCase(2)'>All</a>
</p>
<table id='result_table'>
<colgroup>
<col align='left' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
</colgroup>
<tr id='header_row'>
    <td>Test Group/Test case</td>
    <td>Count</td>
    <td>Pass</td>
    <td>Fail</td>
    <td>Error</td>
    <td>View</td>
</tr>
%(test_list)s
<tr id='total_row'>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>%(count)s</td>
    <td>%(Pass)s</td>
    <td>%(fail)s</td>
    <td>%(error)s</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
""" # variables: (test_list, count, Pass, fail, error)

    REPORT_CLASS_TMPL = r"""
<tr class='%(style)s'>
    <td>%(desc)s</td>
    <td>%(count)s</td>
    <td>%(Pass)s</td>
    <td>%(fail)s</td>
    <td>%(error)s</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:showClassDetail('%(cid)s',%(count)s)">Detail</a></td>
</tr>
""" # variables: (style, desc, count, Pass, fail, error, cid)


    REPORT_TEST_WITH_OUTPUT_TMPL = r"""
<tr id='%(tid)s' class='%(Class)s'>
    <td class='%(style)s'><div class='testcase'>%(desc)s</div></td>
    <td colspan='5' align='center'>

    <!--css div popup start-->
    <a class="popup_link" onfocus='this.blur();' href="javascript:showTestDetail('div_%(tid)s')" >
        %(status)s</a>

    <div id='div_%(tid)s' class="popup_window">
        <div style='text-align: right; color:red;cursor:pointer'>
        <a onfocus='this.blur();' onclick="document.getElementById('div_%(tid)s').style.display = 'none' " >
           [x]</a>
        </div>
        <pre>
        %(script)s
        </pre>
    </div>
    <!--css div popup end-->

    </td>
</tr>
""" # variables: (tid, Class, style, desc, status)


    REPORT_TEST_NO_OUTPUT_TMPL = r"""
<tr id='%(tid)s' class='%(Class)s'>
    <td class='%(style)s'><div class='testcase'>%(desc)s</div></td>
    <td colspan='5' align='center'>%(status)s</td>
</tr>
""" # variables: (tid, Class, style, desc, status)


    REPORT_TEST_OUTPUT_TMPL = r"""
%(id)s: %(output)s
""" # variables: (id, output)



    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # ENDING
    #

    ENDING_TMPL = """<div id='ending'>&nbsp;</div>"""

# -------------------- The end of the Template class -------------------


TestResult = unittest.TestResult


class _TestResult(TestResult):
    # note: _TestResult is a pure representation of results.
    # It lacks the output and reporting ability compares to unittest._TextTestResult.

    def __init__(self, verbosity=1):
        TestResult.__init__(self)
        self.stdout0 = None
        self.stderr0 = None
        self.success_count = 0
        self.failure_count = 0
        self.error_count = 0
        self.verbosity = verbosity

        # result is a list of result in 4 tuple
        # (
        #   result code (0: success; 1: fail; 2: error),
        #   TestCase object,
        #   Test output (byte string),
        #   stack trace,
        # )
        self.result = []

    def startTest(self, test):
        TestResult.startTest(self, test)
        # just one buffer for both stdout and stderr
        self.outputBuffer = StringIO()
        stdout_redirector.fp = self.outputBuffer
        stderr_redirector.fp = self.outputBuffer
        self.stdout0 = sys.stdout
        self.stderr0 = sys.stderr
        sys.stdout = stdout_redirector
        sys.stderr = stderr_redirector


    def complete_output(self):
        """
        Disconnect output redirection and return buffer.
        Safe to call multiple times.
        """
        if self.stdout0:
            sys.stdout = self.stdout0
            sys.stderr = self.stderr0
            self.stdout0 = None
            self.stderr0 = None
        return self.outputBuffer.getvalue()


    def stopTest(self, test):
        # Usually one of addSuccess, addError or addFailure would have been called.
        # But there are some path in unittest that would bypass this.
        # We must disconnect stdout in stopTest(), which is guaranteed to be called.
        self.complete_output()


    def addSuccess(self, test):
        self.success_count += 1
        TestResult.addSuccess(self, test)
        output = self.complete_output()
        self.result.append((0, test, output, ''))
        if self.verbosity > 1:
            sys.stderr.write('ok ')
            sys.stderr.write(str(test))
            sys.stderr.write('\n')
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('.')

    def addError(self, test, err):
        self.error_count += 1
        TestResult.addError(self, test, err)
        _, _exc_str = self.errors[-1]
        output = self.complete_output()
        self.result.append((2, test, output, _exc_str))
        if self.verbosity > 1:
            sys.stderr.write('E  ')
            sys.stderr.write(str(test))
            sys.stderr.write('\n')
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('E')

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        self.failure_count += 1
        TestResult.addFailure(self, test, err)
        _, _exc_str = self.failures[-1]
        output = self.complete_output()
        self.result.append((1, test, output, _exc_str))
        if self.verbosity > 1:
            sys.stderr.write('F  ')
            sys.stderr.write(str(test))
            sys.stderr.write('\n')
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('F')


class HTMLTestRunner(Template_mixin):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, stream=sys.stdout, verbosity=1, title=None, description=None):
        self.stream = stream
        self.verbosity = verbosity
        if title is None:
            self.title = self.DEFAULT_TITLE
        else:
            self.title = title
        if description is None:
            self.description = self.DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION
        else:
            self.description = description

        self.startTime = datetime.datetime.now()


    def run(self, test):
        " Run the given test case or test suite."
        result = _TestResult(self.verbosity)
        test(result)
        self.stopTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.generateReport(test, result)
        # timelapse = self.stopTime-self.startTime
        # print('Time Elapsed: ' + '%s:' % timelapse)
        return result


    def sortResult(self, result_list):
        # unittest does not seems to run in any particular order.
        # Here at least we want to group them together by class.
        rmap = {}
        classes = []
        for n,t,o,e in result_list:
            cls = t.__class__
            if cls not in rmap.keys():
                rmap[cls] = []
                classes.append(cls)
            rmap[cls].append((n,t,o,e))
        r = [(cls, rmap[cls]) for cls in classes]
        return r


    def getReportAttributes(self, result):
        """
        Return report attributes as a list of (name, value).
        Override this to add custom attributes.
        """
        startTime = str(self.startTime)[:19]
        duration = str(self.stopTime - self.startTime)
        status = []
        if result.success_count: status.append('Pass %s'    % result.success_count)
        if result.failure_count: status.append('Failure %s' % result.failure_count)
        if result.error_count:   status.append('Error %s'   % result.error_count  )
        if status:
            status = ' '.join(status)
        else:
            status = 'none'
        return [
            ('Start Time', startTime),
            ('Duration', duration),
            ('Status', status),
        ]


    def generateReport(self, test, result):
        report_attrs = self.getReportAttributes(result)
        generator = 'HTMLTestRunner %s' % __version__
        stylesheet = self._generate_stylesheet()
        heading = self._generate_heading(report_attrs)
        report = self._generate_report(result)
        ending = self._generate_ending()
        output = self.HTML_TMPL % dict(
            title = saxutils.escape(self.title),
            generator = generator,
            stylesheet = stylesheet,
            heading = heading,
            report = report,
            ending = ending,
        )
        self.stream.write(output)


    def _generate_stylesheet(self):
        return self.STYLESHEET_TMPL


    def _generate_heading(self, report_attrs):
        a_lines = []
        for name, value in report_attrs:
            line = self.HEADING_ATTRIBUTE_TMPL % dict(
                    name = saxutils.escape(name),
                    value = saxutils.escape(value),
                )
            a_lines.append(line)
        heading = self.HEADING_TMPL % dict(
            title = saxutils.escape(self.title),
            parameters = ''.join(a_lines),
            description = saxutils.escape(self.description),
        )
        return heading


    def _generate_report(self, result):
        rows = []
        sortedResult = self.sortResult(result.result)
        for cid, (cls, cls_results) in enumerate(sortedResult):
            # subtotal for a class
            np = nf = ne = 0
            for n,t,o,e in cls_results:
                if n == 0: np += 1
                elif n == 1: nf += 1
                else: ne += 1

            # format class description
            if cls.__module__ == "__main__":
                name = cls.__name__
            else:
                name = "%s.%s" % (cls.__module__, cls.__name__)
            doc = cls.__doc__ and cls.__doc__.split("\n")[0] or ""
            desc = doc and '%s: %s' % (name, doc) or name

            row = self.REPORT_CLASS_TMPL % dict(
                style = ne > 0 and 'errorClass' or nf > 0 and 'failClass' or 'passClass',
                desc = desc,
                count = np+nf+ne,
                Pass = np,
                fail = nf,
                error = ne,
                cid = 'c%s' % (cid+1),
            )
            rows.append(row)

            for tid, (n,t,o,e) in enumerate(cls_results):
                self._generate_report_test(rows, cid, tid, n, t, o, e)

        report = self.REPORT_TMPL % dict(
            test_list = ''.join(rows),
            count = str(result.success_count+result.failure_count+result.error_count),
            Pass = str(result.success_count),
            fail = str(result.failure_count),
            error = str(result.error_count),
        )
        return report


    def _generate_report_test(self, rows, cid, tid, n, t, o, e):
        # e.g. 'pt1.1', 'ft1.1', etc
        has_output = bool(o or e)
        tid = (n == 0 and 'p' or 'f') + 't%s.%s' % (cid+1,tid+1)
        name = t.id().split('.')[-1]
        doc = t.shortDescription() or ""
        desc = doc and ('%s: %s' % (name, doc)) or name
        tmpl = has_output and self.REPORT_TEST_WITH_OUTPUT_TMPL or self.REPORT_TEST_NO_OUTPUT_TMPL

        # o and e should be byte string because they are collected from stdout and stderr?
        if isinstance(o, str):
            # TODO: some problem with 'string_escape': it escape \n and mess up formating
            uo = o.encode('utf-8')
            uo = uo.decode('utf-8')
        else:
            uo = o
        if isinstance(e, str):
            # TODO: some problem with 'string_escape': it escape \n and mess up formating
            ue = e.encode('utf-8')
            ue = ue.decode('utf-8')
        else:
            ue = e

        script = self.REPORT_TEST_OUTPUT_TMPL % dict(
            id = tid,
            output = saxutils.escape(uo+ue),
        )

        row = tmpl % dict(
            tid = tid,
            Class = (n == 0 and 'hiddenRow' or 'none'),
            style = n == 2 and 'errorCase' or (n == 1 and 'failCase' or 'none'),
            desc = desc,
            script = script,
            status = self.STATUS[n],
        )
        rows.append(row)
        if not has_output:
            return

    def _generate_ending(self):
        return self.ENDING_TMPL


##############################################################################
# Facilities for running tests from the command line
##############################################################################

# Note: Reuse unittest.TestProgram to launch test. In the future we may
# build our own launcher to support more specific command line
# parameters like test title, CSS, etc.
class TestProgram(unittest.TestProgram):
    """
    A variation of the unittest.TestProgram. Please refer to the base
    class for command line parameters.
    """
    def runTests(self):
        # Pick HTMLTestRunner as the default test runner.
        # base class's testRunner parameter is not useful because it means
        # we have to instantiate HTMLTestRunner before we know self.verbosity.
        if self.testRunner is None:
            self.testRunner = HTMLTestRunner(verbosity=self.verbosity)
        unittest.TestProgram.runTests(self)

main = TestProgram

##############################################################################
# Executing this module from the command line
##############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(module=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, I don't think HTMLTestRunner works with Python 3.x... so you are out of luck.  But let's assume you are trying in Python 2.7...

You have a slew of problems.  You should really read the docs for [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) and [HTMLTestRunner](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tungwaiyip/HTMLTestRunner/master/HTMLTestRunner.py).

However, Consider this example, which achieves similar in python 2:

```
import unittest
from HTMLTestRunner import HTMLTestRunner


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)


class TestBar(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        self.assertFalse(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite = unittest.TestSuite((
        loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestFoo),
        loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestBar)))
    outfile = file('Report.html', 'w')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile,
                            verbosity=2,
                            title='LinkedIn Report',
                            description='This is a demo report')
    runner.run(suite)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMLTestRunner doesn't seem to be actively supported anymore.  I did see a post on Github where when HTMLTestRunner creator tungwaiyip mentions that he doesn't have time to support HTMLTestRunner and he asks if others would continue with it's development.

In that conversation two individuals mention changes they made to the file to get it to work for them.  The post is at:

https://github.com/tungwaiyip/HTMLTestRunner/issues/1

I made that changes detailed in locus2k's comment on Sep 28 and that helped me, although some of his line numbers are off.  I also had to make some edits to the file myself to get things working for me such as:

- line 642 used has_key which needed to be changed to 'if not cls in
  rmap:'
- line 687 encoded a string which errors on stream.write().  Changed to
  not encode the string.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use another HTMLTestRunner it will work fine above python 3.5

```sh
pip install HTMLTestRunner-rv
```

write code like

```py
import unittest
from LoginTest import LoginTest
from EditProfileTest import ProfileEditionTest
from EditAddressTest import EditAddressTest
from CreatePostTest import CreatePostTest
from HTMLTestRunner import HTMLTestRunner

def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginTest))
    suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ProfileEditionTest))
    suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(EditAddressTest))
    suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(CreatePostTest))
    runner = HTMLTestRunner(title='Test report',open_in_browser=True,description='This is a demo report')
    runner.run(suite)
if ____name____ == "____main___":
    suite()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x, change the `stream=outfile` to `output='\\reports'`. `reports` is the destination directory from the current directory in which the HTML report will be generated.

Code:

```py
class MyTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_Issue(self):
        smoke_test = unittest.TestSuite()
        smoke_test.addTests([
            unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(WikiTest.MyWikiTestCase),
            unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(GoogleTest.MyGoogleTest),
        ])

        # outfile = open("SmokeTest.html", "w")

        runner1 = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
            output= "\\repots",
            title='Test Report',
            description='This demonstrates the report output by Prasanna.Yelsangikar.'
        )
       
        runner1.run(smoke_test)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```