# Selenium Python HTMLTestRunner report is not being generated

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium Python test case with some tests and I am using the HTMLTestRunner to generate the html report for the test result.
I am uisng Python 2.7

The report is not being generated.
Does HTMLTestRunner not work with the latest Selenium?

My Selenium Python code implementation is:

```
import unittest
from Base.BaseTestCase import BaseTestCase
from HTMLTestRunner2 import HTMLTestRunner


class RegressionProject_TestCase2(BaseTestCase):


def test_000001_add_a_test_Project(self):
    try:
        print "*** test_add_a_test_project ***"
        # self.login_page.userLogin_valid(Globals.login_username, Globals.login_password)
        menu_bar = MenuBarPage(self.driver)
        administration_page = menu_bar.click_add_project_blank()
        administration_page.add_project("test", Globals.project_description_regression)
        administration_page.click_save()
        administration_page.click_ok_from_dialog()
        self.assertTrue(administration_page.is_add_project_details_saved("test"),
                        "Add test project not saved.  See error log for details")
    except Exception:
        base_page = BasePage(self.driver)
        base_page.save_screenshot("Test add_test_project")
        raise

        # More tests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(RegressionProject_TestCase2))
    dateTimeStamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S')
    test_result_dir = r"E:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\ClearCore - Regression Test\TestReport"
    outfile = file(os.path.join(test_result_dir, "TestReport_" + get_datetime_now() + ".html"), "wb")
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
        stream=outfile,
        title='Test the Report',
        description='Result of tests'
    )
    runner.run(suite)
```

Can anyone help, why is the test report not generating?

I have followed the sample report from the following URL: http://seleniumwithpython.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/html-report-using-htmltestrunner.html

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954381/python-htmltestrunner-not-generating-report

Comment: please fix your indentation, this is not valid code at the moment

Comment: I have updated the indentation.  In PyCharm i used Shift, Ctl, Alt + L and selected whole file to indent.